# change parse order of exp call

Tags: parse-order

I have multiple exp channel call in a page showing widgets.
These calls stay completely different.
Can I set to parse one widget's exp first ?

Hope the widgets will get parsed in the order of rendering. But if I want to set parsing of the last rendered widget first , Is this possible?
Please help if anybody knows?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is no direct method to change parsing orders. Dependent on case you can change it using embeds, conditions, parse=”inward” parameter etc.. What did you mean by "widgets"? Needs to see you template.

Comment: My template have two exp calls like 
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="8"}
    <!--Code showing article list-->
  {/exp:channel:entries}
  
  {exp:channel:entries channel="articles" limit="8"}
    <!--Code showing article list-->
  {/exp:channel:entries}
  
  If I want to parse second exp call first, What should I do?

Comment: use embed. But still question - why do you need it? May be you can use Stash/String/MX Jumper to move results to where do you need it.